# Possible drawbacks of gcAllowVeryLargeObjects?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, gcallowverylargeobjects

After several outOfMemory exceptions, I enabled "gcAllowVeryLargeObjects", it works perfectly fine. I am now wondering why it is not a default option in C# (on a 64-bit platform).

Is it for pure compatibility reasons ? Or am I missing a major drawback of gcAllowVeryLargeObjects ?

Comment: Have you read [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx)? There is only one caution and default value is usually respect *compatibility*.

Comment: look at the clr limitations https://iobservable.net/blog/2013/08/06/clr-limitations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx) says:

> Before enabling this feature, ensure that your application does not include unsafe code that assumes that all arrays are smaller than 2 GB in size. For example, unsafe code that uses arrays as buffers might be susceptible to buffer overruns if it is written on the assumption that arrays will not exceed 2 GB.

So as long you are not using `unsafe` code, there are no drawbacks.

Comment: How does unsafe code look like which "assumes that all arrays are smaller than 2 GB in size"?

Comment: @springy76: have `p1` point to one spot in the array, `p2` to another, and do `(int)(p2 - p1)`.